# wildfly 8 jaas issue

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, jaas, form-authentication, wildfly-8

I was using glassfish for last 3 years and I moved to wildfly 8 recently.
In wildfly i configured to use form based authentication with jaas,
I noticed a strange thing on my change password page on the website.
After login to the website and when i change the password i noticed jaas failed.
When I debug i saw wildfly issuing a jdbcrealm db check everytime a request comes to the restricted area.

Is it good that wildfly check on db everytime for auth even after first successful login ?
I am sure glassfish doesnt do that. ?

And secondly how do I fix jaas auth failing after changing the password ? should I need to login again ?

thank you

**Update**

it was because of cache-type, i havnt defined it in security-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cache-type:

```
<security-domain name="MyRealm" cache-type="default">
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone flagged this for VLQ/NAA, but maybe they wanted you to make it Community Wiki since you're basically repeating what was edited into the question?